# JMeter - Cannot Get Dynamics CSV Values Into My JsonBuilder Request Body

Tags: jmeter, jsonbuilder

I asked a question yesterday about creating a dynamic request body with pre-processors on JMeter. Thanks to Dmitri T, I almost got what I wanted.

Old question here: [JMeter Creating a Pre-Processor that will generate a request body based on a user defined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494791/jmeter-creating-a-pre-processor-that-will-generate-a-request-body-based-on-a-use)

---

But right now, I cannot get dynamic values from my CSV file into the request body.

MY CSV File Example Data:

```
Reading CSV successfully finished, 20 records found:
${id} = 1000011
${email} = a1000011@smartmessage.com
------------
${id} = 1000012
${email} = a1000012@smartmessage.com
------------
${id} = 1000013
${email} = a1000013@smartmessage.com
```

My Pre-Processor that generates request body:

```
    import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
    
    def payload = [:]
    def X = 10 // read user input here somehow
    
    payload.put('message_job_id', '28b0a005-9ef1-475c-b33c-ade900f19e4c')
    payload.put('campaign_group', 'Entegrasyon')
    payload.put('template_id', 'cf585c8c-c675-40d2-b88a-ade900c898d5')
    
    def recipient_list = []
    1.upto(X, { x ->
        def recipient = [:]
        recipient.put('customer_id', vars.get('id') + x)
        def target = [:]
        def address = ['address': vars.get('email' + x)]
        target.put('target', address)
        recipient.put('target', target)
        recipient_list.add(recipient)
    })
    
    payload.put('recipient_list', recipient_list)
    
    
    vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

My Generated Request Body in View Results Tree:

```
  {
        "message_job_id": "28b0a005-9ef1-475c-b33c-ade900f19e4c",
        "campaign_group": "Entegrasyon",
        "template_id": "cf585c8c-c675-40d2-b88a-ade900c898d5",
        "recipient_list": [
            {
                "customer_id": "10000111",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000112",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000113",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000114",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000115",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000116",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000117",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000118",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "10000119",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "100001110",
                "target": {
                    "target": {
                        "address": null
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

As you can see, address key has always null values, but I want to fill this key with email variables in CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build a request body from CSV file and send data from multiple lines in "one shot" - you won't be able to achieve this using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and derivatives because CSV Data Set Config reads next line for each iteration of the each user.

If you need to read multiple lines within the bounds of a single iteration - you will either need to switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime/) or [read the data from the CSV file directly in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-file-read).